# Vertic API authentications issues via Python using Requests package

Tags: python-3.x, api, authentication, python-requests

Trying to connect to Vertiv API to get info regarding PDU data via python using the code bellow, but I keep getting this error. the IP address and logins info are accurate because I was able to connect via the GUI. so I have to set something inside the application for requests to be able to connect?

```
import requests
import json

##### Section: Authenticate to the API
# Set the base URL for the API call
base = 'http://15.10.10.100:8080/api/v1' #This is the URL to an ACS devices API

# Define the final portion of the URL for authenticating and getting an auth token
sessionlogin = '/sessions/login'

# Build the final URL to send
final_url = base + sessionlogin

# Set the POST parameters

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} #Have to set it to JSON
credentials = {'username': 'access_username', 'password': 'user_password'} #Default username and password for an ACS device.

# Send the POST and the parameters
response = requests.post(final_url, data=json.dumps(credentials), headers=headers) #Sending the POST authentication
```

This is the error message I receive.

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection

    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1254, in request

    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1300, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1249, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 974, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 187, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 172, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f535f6b1a90>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Is the website accessible via `curl` from your env?

Comment: yes. I run the following cmd `curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" http://15.10.10.100/api/v1/sessions/login -d '{"username":"access_username","pasword":"user_password"}'` and I get no outputs or error message

Comment: Are you sure the API accepts the credentials as body? If so, then try `requests.post(final_url, json=credentials, headers=headers)`

Comment: As far as the `curl` command is concerned try sending the username and password as follows - `curl --user access_username: user_password http://15.10.10.100/api/v1/sessions/login`

Answer (score 0):

I believe, sending of `headers` won't make any difference because there is no data that is being sent with this request.
try refactoring your request like this:

```
credentials = {
    "username": "access_username",
    "password": "user_password",
}


response = requests.post(
    final_url,
    auth=(credentials["username"], credentials["password"]),
)
```